# Docker from github repository

Tags: docker, image, github, bitbucket

I wish to use a custom docker image that I'm describing from a Dockerfile. I've uploaded this Dockerfile to my own GitHub page and created a repository for it. I'm trying to upload and test laravel projects to an Atlassian BitBucket surface, where if you activate Pipelines, the content will be tested with docker. I wish to use my own docker image here. How can I set the bitbucket-pipelines.yml to pull down the image that would be created with the help of the Dockerfile? Or This is just not how I should make it? If not, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the image yourself and push it to Docker Hub, then you can reference it in Pipelines as:

```
image: yourdockerusername/yourimage
```

In fact, you can host it anywhere:

```
image: your.docker.registry:port/user/image
```

Bitbucket Pipelines also allows you to build the image, too, you can push to any repository from there.

Comment: Cheers Buddy! :)